# Auth()::user() is not working in multi authentication in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-breeze

in my  project , I am using the **breeze** package for authentication

in  my case I wanna have **2 dashboard**

the normal Auth::user() is working for normal user as u know!

### but for admin , after attemp() was successfull but it can not make Auth()::user() and it return the null

i added my admins-web guard to config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
    //My Guards for admin
    'admins-web'=>[
        'driver'=>'session',
        'provider'=>'admins'
    ]

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    //My provider for admin
    'admins'=>[
        'driver'=>'eloquent',
        'model'=>App\Models\Admin::class
    ]

],
```

here is my **AdminAuthenticatedSessionController** class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Auth\AdminLoginRequest;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
//use Auth;

class AdminAuthenticatedSessionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the login view.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function show()
    {
        return view('Admin.login');
    }

    public function dashboard(){
        return view('Admin.dashboard');
    }
    /**
     * Handle an incoming authentication request.
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function store(AdminLoginRequest $request)
    {

        //dd($request->only('email','password'));
        $request->authenticate();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::AdminHome);
    }


    /**
     * Destroy an authenticated session.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::guard('admins-web')->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect('/admin/login');
    }
}
```

and here is my **AdminLoginRequest** that is in Requests/Auth Folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class AdminLoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate the request's credentials.
     *
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
      
        $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

        

        if (! Auth::guard('admins-web')->attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->filled('remember'))) {
            RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => __('auth.failed'),
            ]);
        }

        RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
    }

    /**
     * Ensure the login request is not rate limited.
     *
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function ensureIsNotRateLimited()
    {
        if (! RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts($this->throttleKey(), 5)) {
            return;
        }

        event(new Lockout($this));

        $seconds = RateLimiter::availableIn($this->throttleKey());

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => trans('auth.throttle', [
                'seconds' => $seconds,
                'minutes' => ceil($seconds / 60),
            ]),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the rate limiting throttle key for the request.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function throttleKey()
    {
        return Str::lower($this->input('email')).'|'.$this->ip();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Auth::guard('admins-web')`